# c#: assigning from nullable types

Tags: c#, nullable

If I have a nullable "decimal? d" and I want to assign d to non nullable e, what is the proper way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
decimal e = d ?? 0.0;
```

Comment: Love the null coalescing operator.  This expands to 'decimal e = d != null ? d : 0.0;'

Comment: Exactly, to me this is short and sweet and allows you to treat the nullable type succinctly.  You don't have to worry about using the .HasValue or .Value properties either.

Comment: Echoing other comments - this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 10):

```
decimal e;
if(d.HasValue) 
{
    e = d.Value;
}
```

Comment: -1 for declaring a variable that will go out of scope after you assign to it.

Comment: That's not a reason to downvote. It answers the question, and if someone doesn't know that e needs to be declared outside an if block, they have bigger problems than Nullable types.

Comment: (You'd notice his error quickly, you wouldn't notice possible System.InvalidOperationExceptions as quickly).

Comment: Edited to move 'decimal e;' declaration outside the scope (all correct now).

Answer (score 2):

You need to determine whether you even can, i.e. whether the nullable d has a value or not.

```
if (d.HasValue) { e = d.Value; } else { /* now what */ }
```

Another interesting case comes up quite commonly where you want to assign to a nullable using a ternary, in which case you have to cast to make both branches have the same type.

```
d = foo ? 45 : (int?)null;
```

Note the case of null to (int?) so that both branches have the same type.

Comment: Good point on the ternary operator thing.  Always kind of annoyed me I have to cast null to a type here :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
decimal e;

if (d.HasValue)
{
    e = d.Value;
}
```

Comment: and what value should e take when d is null?

Comment: I could say -1 for possible 'System.InvalidOperationException' but i wont.

Comment: This answer is right now, but only after copying Phaedrus' answer.

Comment: Jeez, don't get so testy Graphain.  I fixed my invalid code.  And nice catch, Phaedrus.  I rushed my answer.

Comment: And technically, I didn't copy the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I usually go with something like this:

```
decimal e = d.HasValue ? d.Value : decimal.Zero;
```

The reason here is that I'm a fan of ternary operations and I usually assign the value I would get if I had perfermed a failed `TryParse()` for the type I am dealing with.  For `decimal` that would be `decimal.Zero`, for `int` it would be `0` as well.